# IndexOutOfBounds looping though subviews?

Tags: objective-c, ios, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a nethod to refresh the content of a UIScrollView. Within the ScrollView there are several UIImageViews and some UILabels.

I do clean the content of the scrollView with the following code:

```
for (int i = [publicationsScrollView.subviews count] -1; i>=0; i--) {
    NSLog(@"Deleting SubView: %@", [[publicationsScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] class]);
    if ([[publicationsScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] || [[publicationsScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIButtonLongTap class]] || [[publicationsScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] || [[publicationsScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Deleting SubView: %@", [[publicationsScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] class]);
        [[publicationsScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ([[publicationsScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[iCarousel class]]) {
        NSLog(@"carousel: View is in Scrollview");
    }
}
```

This code ran fine for some days. Now i recieve an error during refresh in console:

```
refreshWorkSpace: deleting all subviews (11)
2011-11-25 14:04:52.826 CatalogService[45054:fb03] Deleting SubView: UILabel
2011-11-25 14:04:52.827 CatalogService[45054:fb03] Deleting SubView: UILabel
2011-11-25 14:04:52.839 CatalogService[45054:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1e8c052 0x231fd0a 0x1e78db8 0x6945 0x5826 0x1e8dec9 0xddc5c2 0xddc55a 0xe81b76 0xe8203f 0xe81bab 0xecfa99 0xed1407 0xe0193f 0xe01c56 0xde8384 0xddbaa9 0x28b6fa9 0x1e601c5 0x1dc5022 0x1dc390a 0x1dc2db4 0x1dc2ccb 0x28b5879 0x28b593e 0xdd9a9b 0x2e6d 0x2de5 0x1
```

I can not understand what's happening here. I loop through the subviews (count should give me the number of existing subviews !?). Why could the Index be out of Bounds !?

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure that subviews are not removed by other functions at the same time? Are you sure that there's no other source fragments which can affect this bug?

Comment: I'm crawling through the code right now to check for that. I couldn't find something up till now.

Comment: It always crashes at the same subview ...

Comment: does it crash is the state you show us? with line '[[publicationsScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];' commented out?

Comment: I just saw that i commented out the line `//[[publicationsScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];` in my post. that's the line where it crashed (always if "i" == 3, at the third subview to be removed)

Comment: Just to know is `subviews objectAtIndex: removefromsuperview` AppStore safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect the exception is being thrown on this line:

```
if ([[publicationsScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[iCarousel class]]) {
```

in the case where `[[publicationsScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview]` has just executed there will no longer be an object at index 'i'. This would only happen if the last subview in the array was one of the types you delete - otherwise the access would be harmless.

To fix, you could just add a `continue` after the `removeFromSuperview` call.

Comment: that seems to work. Thanks for helping in such basic question!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try replacing for loop with a fast enumeration, like:

```
for (UIView *aView in publicationsScrollview.subviews) {

  .... rewrite code to reference aView instead of using objectAtIndex
}
```

and see if you get the same behavior.

Comment: its just strange to me that you say its crashing on i=3 but the crash log seems to suggest its gone over its bounds at i=10

Comment: He's modifying the subview array by removing subviews, so a fast enumeration will throw an exception about mutating the array during iteration.

Answer (score 0):

In the first if, if it entered you remove the subview. So, you decreased the subviews count array.
After that you try again to take the subview, in the second if, and this subview was removed, that's why it's crashing.